# Grouping csv data using NiFi processors

Tags: csv, apache-nifi

I have a set of 4 columned csv data where records have same value for the first column for 5 rows.Then again the value remains same for the first column for the next 5 rows and so on.

Sample data:

```
a,21,51,xxx
a,22,52,xxx
a,23,53,xxx
a,24,54,xxx
a,25,55,xxx
b,21,61,yyy
b,22,62,yyy
b,23,63,yyy
b,24,64,yyy
b,25,65,yyy
...........
```

But sometimes the records come in arbitrarily as:

```
a,21,51,xxx
a,22,52,xxx
a,23,53,xxx
b,21,61,yyy
b,22,62,yyy
a,24,54,xxx
a,25,55,xxx
b,23,63,yyy
b,24,64,yyy
b,25,65,yyy
...........
```

Is there any way of grouping such data based on its first column using NiFi processors?

Any answers would be helpful.

Thanks

Comment: you wants to group the rows if first column of the row is same.Is this your use case right?

Comment: yes That is my usecase

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to do this with the RouteText processor using the Grouping Regular Expression, which says:

> "Specifies a Regular Expression to evaluate against each line to
>   determine which Group the line should be placed in. The Regular
>   Expression must have at least one Capturing Group that defines the
>   line's Group. If multiple Capturing Groups exist in the Regular
>   Expression, the Group from all Capturing Groups. Two lines will not be
>   placed into the same FlowFile unless the they both have the same value
>   for the Group (or neither line matches the Regular Expression). For
>   example, to group together all lines in a CSV File by the first
>   column, we can set this value to "(.*?),.*". Two lines that have the
>   same Group but different Relationships will never be placed into the
>   same FlowFile."

I think you can use that in conjunction with a Matching Strategy of Matches Regular Expression and just use .* for that expression so that every line matches.

Then for the grouping expression use the example above to group by the first column (.*?),.*

Comment: I used the above solution but with few changes.For grouping expression expression I used:(.*?),.*

Comment: Thanks a lot for your timely help.